# Rails: Run Test Suite of Single Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It seems like a simple thing but I can't seem to find the proper way to run tests from a single model. For example, run all tests in the test/controllers/user_controller_test.rb suite.

Answer (score 1):

`rake test TEST=test/controllers/user_controller_test.rb`